# "Сладко(-)сливочный"

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "сладкосливочное масло" или "сладко сливочное"?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о масле, сделанном из сладких сливок, то, думаю, **сладкосливочный**.
Хотя тут действительно есть некоторая неоднозначность. Можно понимать и так, что оно и сладкое, и сливочное. Потому как кисло-сливочное отнюдь не из "кислых сливок", а из тех же сладких, но с молочнокислыми добавками (заквасками).
Надо поискать, может в каком словаре есть.

Answer (score 1):

У Лопатина в Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации есть разъяснение. Через дефис пишутся прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки качества  (преимущественно цвета или вкуса).
Это правило распространяется и на любые индивидуально-авторские образования, обозначающие сочетания признаков.

Comment: Никаким боком здесь не оттенок качества.
Здесь сливочный - вообще не качество, а относительное прилагательное, а вот "кислый" - под вопросом. Оно может, конечно, быть качественным если имеется в виду вкус (кислый - кислее), но скорее всего здесь тоже относительное значение - способ приготовления. Как солёный огурец.

Answer (score 0):

пишется слитно. образовано от словосочетания, в котором слова связаны способом согласования - сладкие сливки. как железнодорожный - от железная дорога, синеглазый - от синие глаза и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно ГОСТ Р 52969-2008. Масло сливочное. - сладко-сливочное и кисло-сливочное пишется через дефис

Comment: Согласно указанию т. Ким Чен Ира подготовлен ГОСТ на использование русского языка в текстах ГОСТов.

Answer (score 0):

НАша система орфографии относительна устойчива. Но вот как раз написание сложных прилагательных сейчас претерпевает изменения, не всегда зафиксированные словарями. Одно и то же слово  в разных словарях может быть зафиксировано по-разному. Классическое:  если образовано от подчинительного словосочетания - пишу слитно, от сочинительного - пишу через дефис - не всегда работает. Формируются постепенно другие закономерности. В новых справочниках они стали называться исключениями, но их неограниченное количество говорит как раз о новых тенденциях .Так, если в первой части сложного прилагательного есть суффикс относительного (оканчивается на -ско-. например,)такие прилагательный пишутся через дефис. Ну а то что свой вклад могут внести и ГОСТы - не исключено. Подобные примеры уже были. (Восточносибирская крепость - слитно в соответствии с  правилом, а равнина Восточно-Сибирская - вклад картографов  в русскую орфографию)

Answer (score 0):

У меня возникает аналогичная проблема при написании сочетания **взаимно(?)однозначная** функция. Во избежание "красного подчеркивания" набираю слова через пробел. Но мне кажется,все-таки, что это одно слово, возможно, написанное через дефис. Что скажут профессионалы?

Answer (score 0):

По аналогии с написанием кисло-сливочный можно рекомендовать дефисное написание.

Comment: Аналогия - штука опасная. Здесь несколько разные вещи. См. мой старый ответ.